# Is there something similar to react storybook for native swift and java devs?

Tags: java, swift

My team is looking for something similar to storybook for native mobile development. We're building a design system and need to develop isolated and encapsulated components independently. Any idea if there is a way to enable swift and java on storybook? Or maybe another tool that serves this purpose?

Comment: did you manage to find something like this? I've been looking for something similar but with no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

*Found this after a quick online search*. Xcode contains Liveness since Xcode 7 or something. It basically enables you to have Interface Builder render your custom views. I always use it in my Storyboards. It saves time on making adjustments. Given that all UI related classes are in a separate framework.

SwiftUI has this ability with it's live view option.

Comment: yes, tried that already. Unfortunately, it's closed within the swift ecosystem. I would love something open that can be shared. Our goal is to have a unified design language and centralized documentation for all platforms. That doesn't solve the problem.